# Orderby title and between letters WP Query

Tags: php, wordpress

I know that I can use `'orderby' => 'title` to order my posts or users with WP Query, but what if I wanted to order by title *and* orderby by A to C?

How can I write something like this?

Comment: `range` isn't a valid value for the `orderby` parameter...

Comment: Yeah I know, but is there a way for me to order all the users and display only them from A to C?

Comment: There's not a standard way to do that using `WP_Query`...You'll need to query for all posts, orderby the title, and then only output the posts in your loop if the title begins with A-C